# Recover ext3 files from hard disk with bad sector

Tags: debian, hard-drive, ext3, data-recovery, fsck

I have a folder of about 5GB that suddenly disappeared. When I checked its hard disk, I found out it has bad sector for about 2-3MB on this folder. Maybe it is on the folder's pointer.

The partition is EXT3 , and operating system is Debian.

I tried the `fsck` command , but it hasn't worked.

What should I do? How can I recover data? Any program or command?

Answer (score 3):

If fsck complained about unreadable disk following may help you:

First, you should connect additional hard drive of the same or greater size. Then copy all data from old, failing drive to newly connected with dd_rescue or similar tool (it will skip unreadable portions of the source hdd). 
After that, disconnect old disk. Now try fsck on new hdd.

I suggest you to always create a copy of failing drive and experimenting with a copy.

Comment: Do you know any recovery software that could recovery all data that is lost?

Comment: @ArashMousavi There is no guarantee to recover data if some part of the hard drive has failed. You may recover all, or some, or nothing. If you must have the data back, restore it from your backups.